# How to use multiple password policies in .NET Core Identity?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

We have our users divided into groups. Each group has a different password policy. What i want to achieve is to dynamically load a password policy related to a particular user, before he/she wants to change a password and then validate the new password using this policy.

I know i can globally setup default password policy per entire application in startup class:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
});
```

It works great but we want to have user-based policies loaded at runtime.

The only solution that comes to my mind right now is to create my own IPasswordValidator implementation, where i could simply load my password policy and do everything by myself (meaning check if there is a lowercase letter in a new password if it was required by the policy attached to this user etc.). But before i start implementing this i wonder if there is a prettier solution.

Ideally what i would like to achieve is to validate user's password using a dynamically generated PasswordOptions object.

Comment: This isn't supported. It actually requires a fair bit of infrastructure to achieve: more than you would think. It's not just about the policies themselves; there would need to exist ways to migrate users from one policy to another, and handle applying policy updates. None of that exists in Identity for password policies.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thanks for your answer. This is what i rather expected to hear. I just thought maybe i missed some kind of mechanism in the framework that would let me do this.